# sending a cookie or some sort to front end (react) when passport facebook failureRedirect runs

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

i have this setup in my app where you can register using the conventional registration form filling up your email etc, and also added a method to login/register using passport auth ie. passport facebook.

the problem i faced is i wanna check database if certain facebook registered email is already used so i have this in the facebookStrategy

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/api/auth/facebook/callback`,
    profileFields: ['displayName', 'email']
}, async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    try {
        console.log(profile, 'profile')
        const checkEmail = await users.findOne({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    { email: profile?.emails[0].value },
                    {
                        [Op.or]: [
                        { provider: 'website' },
                        {provider: "google"}       
                    ]}
               ]
            }
        })
        if (checkEmail) return cb(null, false, { message: 'Email already registered' })
        ...
```

with the callback function like this

```
Router.get('/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook',
        {
            failureRedirect: `http://localhost:3000/users/register`,
        }),
    function (req, res) {
        const token = createToken({ id: req.user.id })
        req.flash('test', 'testagain')
        res.cookie('jwt', token)
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/passport-login')
    });
```

how can i run a function before failureRedirect is called to send a cookie or some sort that will be get on /users/register page render and if cookie exist, i can use that cookie to show a toast